# How to perform full text search under a given path and under pages that are Activated only in AEM 6 using Query builder?

Tags: aem, query-builder

I want to perform a full text search but under a specific path and under pages that are Activated or Published only.

So if we find the text under `/content/skynet/contact-us/jcr:content/content/slider/items` and the page contact-us.html is not activated then this hit should be ignored

```
path=/content/skynet
type=cq:Page
group.p.or=true
group.1_fulltext=icon-phone
group.1_fulltext.relPath=jcr:content

property=cq:lastReplicationAction
property.value=Activate

p.limit=1
p.offset=0
```

Comment: Using that property (cq:lastReplicationAction) will work only on author, by default that property is not copied to publish.

Answer (score 1):

Your property `cq:lastReplicationAction` would be on the `cq:PageContent` node and not on `cq:Page`. So giving a relative path to the property should fix your issue.

```
path=/content/skynet
type=cq:Page
fulltext=icon-phone
fulltext.relPath=jcr:content
property=jcr:content/cq:lastReplicationAction
property.value=Activate
p.limit=-1 //To display all the results
```